# How to shorten file path url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, filepath

Is that possible to shorten   a file path and get the file with that shortened path?

Ex: In my rails public folder I have a file like

```
/users/000/001/991/image.png
```

I want to shorten it like `/<dynamic user_name>/image.png`. But when I use that shortened url I want to refer to the original file path. I googled but couldn't find a way. Appreciate if I get any reference.

Comment: Create a symbolic link to your file path.

Comment: If I have 1000 images I need to create symlink for all?

Answer (score 0):

Logic depends as per your need and current DB structure. some possible solution could be 
-If your path is fix, just store image name. and while creating full path join +
-If path is no fixed and storing path in DB, you can create one column more column and store unique id(any integer or alpanumeric as per logic but unique value) and use that unique value to replace path